How do I get Context object in Jetpack Compose in Preview mode?
I am trying to use Preview mode in one of my Composables in Jetpack Compose. I just finished changing the function signature of my Composable to pass in all the different fields and functions I need, instead of getting them from my ViewModel which I was passing in, which has everything related to data (which was painful enough).
Now I’m running into the problem where I need to use the Context, in order to get access to the assets directory from a non-Composable utility class:
ClaimFactionSelectorApplication.appContext.assets.open("data/applicationText.json")

I am getting the Context in my Application like this:
@HiltAndroidApp
class ClaimFactionSelectorApplication: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appContext = applicationContext
    }
    companion object {
        lateinit var appContext: Context
    }
}

In a situation where I am using Preview mode, how can I get the necessary Context?

preview is executed on your local machine, you can't access android assets there.

Also, why would you even need that? You just pass simple POJOs and (probably empty) functions to your preview, there is no need for a Context object. You shouldn't even have parameters of that type in your composables. If a composable needs a Context, it can always get one itself with LocalContext.current, no need for a parameter.

Thanks, I've come up with a way to read the assets without the context, since I can't get one in preview mode.

@DaveWesterman may I ask for the solution you came up with?

@DaveWesterman Please post your answer so that this question isn't perpetually unanswered.

Since I couldn't get the context, I ended up doing this to access the file. It's a hack, but it's the only thing I could get to work.
            applicationTextMap = if (ClaimDeckAssemblerApplication.appContext == null) {
                // need this for Preview mode
                jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(
                    File("src/main/assets/data/applicationText.json").readText()
                )
            } else {
                jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(
                    ClaimDeckAssemblerApplication.appContext!!.assets.open("data/applicationText.json")
                )
            }

